# Deploying jQuery Mobile app to Google App Engine

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, jquery-mobile

I created an app using `PyCharm`, the project directory is made up of the following:

```
My Project
 ______main.py
 ______app.yaml
 ______templates
 ______html
          _____js
                __________profilePage.js
                __________other .js files
          _____images
          _____css
          _____index.html
          _____profilePage.html
```

And the `app.yaml:`

```
application: my app id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /js/(.*\.js)
  mime_type: application/javascript
  static_files: js/\1
  upload: js/(.*\.js)

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /html
  static_dir: html

libraries:
- name: webapp2
 version: "2.5.2"
```

I tried deploying the app to Google app engine using the Google App Engine Launcher and it deployed successfully but it redirects to my `MainHandler` in main.py which i custom designed to just print "hello world".How do i get my app to display the contents of index.html instead?

Comment: We won't be able to tell you without seeing the contents of your app.yaml

Comment: I just included that now.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is the

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Catches everything that reaches it .

Move it down the list.

app.yaml handler processing is in order.  The first match gets the request.